# Work out the maximum size of an image?

Tags: java, image, awt

I am creating a little game in Java and I have an image which gets rotated.

[image]

As you can see in the two images below, there is a giant ship which slowly rotates in the game, but when it gets to a certain point it gets cut off (due to its own little BufferedImage).

Heres my rendering code:

```
public void drawImageRotated(BufferedImage img, double x, double y, double scale,    double angle) {
        x -= xScroll;
        y -= yScroll;  
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage((int)(img.getWidth() * 1.5D), (int)(img.getHeight() * 1.5D), 2);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)image.getGraphics();
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle), image.getWidth() / 2, image.getHeight() / 2);
        g.drawImage(img, image.getWidth() / 2 - img.getWidth() / 2, image.getHeight() / 2 - image.getHeight() / 2, null);
        g2d.drawImage(image, (int)(x-image.getWidth()*scale/2), (int)(y-image.getHeight()*scale/2), (int)(image.getWidth()*scale), (int)(image.getHeight()*scale), null);
        g.dispose();      
 }
```

Back to the matter at hand, how can i work out the maximum x and y size of an image during rotation so I can compensate with my buffered images size?

Comment: Rotating the image will change its size, you need take into account this change. Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165977/java-image-rotation) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156518/rotate-an-image-in-java) for examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a basically rectangular image which is rotated around its center, the maximum width and height during rotation will be when a diagonal of the image rectangle is horizontal or vertical. This diagonal distance could be computed with the Pythagorean Theorem and used for the width and height of the `BufferedImage`.

```
    int size = (int) Math.sqrt((img.getWidth() * img.getWidth()) + (img.getHeight() * img.getHeight()));
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(size, size, 2);
    // The rest of your code as before
```

Answer (score 1):

> how can i work out the maximum x and y size of an image during rotation so I can compensate with my buffered images size?

```
double sin = Math.abs(Math.sin(angle));
double cos = Math.abs(Math.cos(angle));
int w = image.getWidth();
int h = image.getHeight();
int neww = (int)Math.floor(w*cos+h*sin);
int newh = (int)Math.floor(h*cos+w*sin);
```

The above code was taken from this example: [Java(SWING) working with Rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636292/javaswing-working-with-rotation/3636789#3636789)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to rotate the actual `Graphics` object, draw the image, and restore the rotation:

```
AffineTransform old = g2d.getTransform();
g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle), x + image.getWidth() / 2, y + image.getWidth() / 2);
g2d.drawImage(image, x, y, null);
g2d.setTransform(old);
```

Comment: Can you please go into more depth about what that does?

If that's what I think it is, it would rotate everything in my scene, this is not what i'm looking for.

Comment: @ShaunWild It does not rotate everything. It only rotates the image you are drawing.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider `width` being the width of the original image, `height` its original height and `angle` the rotation angle value in radians.

According to my calculations, the size of the rotated image is something like this:

```
rotatedWidth = Math.cos(angle) * width + Math.sin(angle) * height;
rotatedHeight = Math.sin(angle) * width + Math.cos(angle) * height;
```

You may also need to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165977/java-image-rotation/12166204) thread as well, as it may help.